# How can I permanently save the last code until next restart in vim

Tags: vim

So my question is if I am writing some code in vim & then want to go back 20 minutes earlier, then I type `:earlier 20m` in vim. But this doesn't work if I exit the vim once or even reboot by system. I understand that it is stored into the temporary registers and once vim restarts, it cleans the whole register buffers. But is there any way I can save the last changes & apply some undo mechanisms. Actually I work on some big project files & if something wrong occurs, I can not go back.

Comment: I would recommend using some version control like git to achieve what you want.

Comment: If your Vim has support for Python you might want to take a look at the [gundo plugin](https://github.com/sjl/gundo.vim).  Combine it with `undodir` described below.

Answer (score 5):

In Vim 7.3 or later, you can use an undo file.

Put this in your .vimrc.

```
set undofile
```

By default this will save 100 actions to undo. If you want more, you can set it manually by adding this to your .vimrc, with whatever number you want:

```
set undolevels=100
```

Persistent undo will create undo files in the same directories as the files you actually work on. If you want to put these in a separate directory so they don't clutter your filesystem, add this to your .vimrc:

```
set undodir=~/.vim/undo
```

Then, you need to actually make the directory. From the command line:

```
mkdir ~/.vim/undo
```

I would look into using version control instead of relying on vim's persistent undo to track changes in your projects.

Comment: Vim 7.3 was [released](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/vim_announce/ZsAu_RUjVUs/wrLPfs0dJeIJ) almost 5 years ago.  `undodir` is pretty stable these days.

Comment: Also, only the first line is really needed. Without undodir set you'll still get the persistent undo feature, but the undo files will be scattered about, living next to the files they refer to. Whether you prefer to tidy up with undodir or not is up to your preferences.